# How to write calculation correctly for program that checks what numbers between 1 and 1000 are dividable by entered value ( int variables)

Tags: c#, integer

I am writing a program that first lets a user enter a number between 1 and 10, and then checks what numbers between 1 and 1000 are dividable by that number.
both variables used are int variables, so for example if a user enters 4, it should read: 1  8 12 16 etc.

thusfar i have the following code:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Getal1 = 1;
            int Getal2;

            Getal2 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);//textbox1 to getal2

            for (Getal1 = 1; Getal1 <= 1000; Getal1++)//// for loop.
            {
                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "\r\n" + Getal1 / Getal2 +  "\r\n";
            }
        }
```

the textbook mentions using the following code : Getal1 % Getal2.. i tried adding it after the calculation above, but this didnt work.. math is not my strong point at all..
does someone have an explanation on this?
maybe if Getal1 % Getal2 = 0??.. im really guessing here..

thanks for any help in advance,

Stefan

I tried adding code from the textbook, expecting the program to work correctly, right now it does give a result, but not a correct result.. for example if i enter 2 it starts the sequence with the numbers 123..

Comment: Your guess is quite correct: if `Getal1 % Getal2 == 0` then `Getal1` is divisible by `Getal2`. Only append `Getal1` to the text box when the above condition holds.

Comment: Have a look at the following documentation to better understand why this works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (Getal1 = 1; Getal1 <= 1000; Getal1++)//// for loop.
        {
            if (Getal1 % Getal2 == 0)
            {
                textBox2.Text += Getal1.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It works!  i guess it didnt before because it still divides integers even if the outcome isn't  whole? I will check the link to documentation that was provided to see if it explains it..

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the division checking whatsoever by starting with the number introduced by the user and then adding this number in the loop. This way you will never get a number that is not dividable.

For example:

1. if user inputs `4`, you start with `4`
2. than you add `4` to it and get `8`
3. add `4` again, get `12` and so on

```cs
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Getal2 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);//textbox1 to getal2

            for (int Getal1 = Getal2; Getal1 <= 1000; Getal1 += Getal2)//// for loop.
            {
                textBox2.Text += Getal1 + "\r\n";
            }
        }
```

Comment: yes, but this is not what the course asks for.. thank you for your effort anyway.

Comment: @StefanN this is exactly what it asks for: output numbers between 1 and 1000 that are dividable by the number inputted by the user